# BjyAuthorize Deny All, Super User, User Spoofing

Tags: zend-framework, root, spoof, bjyauthorize

I'm building a web system with no public views (except for login fo course).
So far, I got Bjyauthorize running with zfcUser, what I would like to do is:

1) Guard all routes but the login, so I don't have to be writting guards for every single page while I'm in development and for security reasons this would be a plus for me, because I wouldnt accidentaly expose any part that is not intended to be exposed.

2) I need the admin Role to be able to retrieve any route, any controller, disregarding any guards.

3) I'd like to add the functionality for the Super user to be able to spoof any user aka make the system think I'm that specific user, so I could test my system functionality through the eyes of a specific user.

We already have a system in PHP, MVC which makes all of these and we are migrating to Zend, so this would be a necessity for us.

I don't expect a full answer of every single Item, Some guides, tutorials and above all a concise answer if this is achievable through BjyAuthorize would be much appreciated :D

Comment: Did you managed to do that? I want the same thing...Thanks!

Comment: I ditched ZF2 in favor of Laravel, way easier! way nicer!